# What`s the difference between AWS Route 53 Weighted and Geoproximity routing policies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, amazon-route53

They seem pretty similar to me. Both divide traffic based on weights configuration(Weighted - weight, Geoproximity - bias).

Answer (score 2):

From [Choosing a routing policy - Amazon Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html):

- **Weighted routing policy** – Use to route traffic to multiple resources in proportions that you specify.
- **Geoproximity routing policy** – Use when you want to route traffic based on the location of your resources and, optionally, shift traffic from resources in one location to resources in another.

Examples:

- Use **Weighted** when you want to send 80% to one destination and 20% to another
- Use **Geoproximity** to divide the world into sections and route traffic based on the source, such as sending all traffic in Oceania to Sydney and all traffic from South America to Ohio. The *bias* can be used to make particular sections 'bigger' to make some sections larger than others.

Answer (score 1):

For Geoproximity, AWS will route the traffic based on your user and your resource locations.

> Geoproximity routing lets Amazon Route 53 route traffic to your
> resources based on the geographic location of your users and your
> resources. You can also optionally choose to route more traffic or
> less to a given resource by specifying a value, known as a bias. A
> bias expands or shrinks the size of the geographic region from which
> traffic is routed to a resource.

If you have two locations set up, this means that if 90% of your users come from (or are near) location A, your traffic will flow to location A aswel.

While for weighted:

> Weighted routing lets you associate multiple resources with a single domain name (example.com) or subdomain name (acme.example.com) and choose how much traffic is routed to each resource. This can be useful for a variety of purposes, including load balancing and testing new versions of software.

This means that for weighted you will specify how much traffic should flow to which target. This could be done for loadbalancing for example. This does mean that for weighted users close to location A might end up on servers in location B

More information can be found on the [development guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-weighted)